# pandas: Using built-in and customized aggregation function together?

Tags: python-3.x, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

I used the following code:

```
s=df.groupby('version').agg({'duration':['mean','std'],'ts':['min','max']).reset_index()
s.columns=s.columns.map("_".join)
```

The results work fine.

Then I tried to add one more aggregate function `quantile(.25)`

```
s=df.groupby('version').agg({'duration':['mean','std', quantile(.25)],'ts':['min','max']}).reset_index()
s.columns=s.columns.map("_".join)
```

Then get the following error:

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-d4857cf7740e> in <module>()
----> 1 s=df.groupby('version').agg({'duration':['mean','std', quantile(.25)],'ts':['min','max']}).reset_index()
      2 s.columns=s.columns.map("_".join)
      3 s

NameError: name 'quantile' is not defined
```

What would be the proper way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the quantile operation in a lambda function:

```
> import pandas as pd
> import numpy as np
> df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration': np.random.rand(10), 
                     'Version': [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4]})
> df

    Duration    Version
0   0.843479    1
1   0.028724    1
2   0.605053    2
3   0.548231    2
4   0.223244    3
5   0.883418    3
6   0.772413    4
7   0.100166    4
8   0.865734    4
9   0.865839    4

> df.groupby('Version').agg({'Duration' : [min, max, lambda x: x.quantile(.25)]}

        Duration
        min         max         <lambda>
Version         
1       0.028724    0.843479    0.232413
2       0.548231    0.605053    0.562437
3       0.223244    0.883418    0.388287
4       0.100166    0.865839    0.604351
```